# notation sup{|f-f(\bullet-y)|}

Tags: notation, sobolev-spaces

my question is probably rather simple I just never came across this notation:

$sup\{||f-f(\bullet-y)||: f\in K\}\rightarrow 0$ and I cannot realy seem to find what it indicates. I am guessing it means something in the sense of

$sup\{||g||: g(x)=(f(x)-f(x-y)) \forall x; f\in K||\}\rightarrow 0$

Does anybody know this notation and can verify or clarify this for me?
If it makes a difference: The notation came across while looking into Sobolev Spaces.

Thankyou very much!

Comment: for $y\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: yes, sorry, forgot about that. I am mainly wondering about the $\bullet$...

Comment: Indeed the function $g=f-f(\cdot-y)$ is defined by $g(x)=f(x)-f(x-y)$ for every suitable $x$. Is this your question?

Comment: That was exactly my question! Thank you!